# How present the result table below the last result query table, SSMS 2017

Tags: sql-server, ssms, windows-10

os: window 10
SSMS 2017, v17.9.1

I watched youtube videos of SSMS running two different queries and the last result was displayed below the last table.
Example that I am referring [in youtube](https://youtu.be/7h9uuILngp0?t=596).
Now when I run a new query It does not conserve the last table there, I only can see the last result table.
I want to see the last two or three tables there in the same windows to compare them, Is it possible?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, actually if you run two queries at the same time it should automatically display to separate windows with the result.

Comment: omg, thanks pal, really I was driving me crazy finding how do that.